# Use a wordpress page to display a certain category

Tags: categories, customization

I'm trying to set up a portfolio page on my wordpress website, and I would like the following construct:

- /blog/ where I blog all kinds of things, including portfolio entries
- /portfolio/ where I show just posts from my portfolio category
- some regular /pagename/ pages (about, contact, etc)

I want the portfolio section to have a separate style (and even html probably) than a regular category overview. So if someone clicks one of the categories in my blog they still see the normal /category/randomcategory/ overview page. This means I can't just change the category php page and/or the css, because the portfolio page is different from the regular view.

Is there a way to set up my page so that it shows the posts in the category portfolio the way I want?

Comment: Hmm, or should I use custom post types for this? I only just found out about those...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [page of posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#A_Page_of_Posts) example pulls posts from one category, it uses a custom field to designate the category, which in turn makes the page template re-usable on other pages with other categories to, if you so choose..

You can style that template however you like..

Hope that helps..

Comment: Finally had time to look at this, works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy .
You can see in the category template section that you can use either category-10.php or category-portfolio.php (in case your portfolio category id is 10 and the slug is "portfolio") to override the default archive.php file.

This way, you can customize the HTML/CSS in the new file you create  and it will have an effect only on the portfolio template.

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to create custom page template. Refer to [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages) to see how to create it.

Second, on that page (you can copy from your page.php/index.php, the important part is:

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Find that piece and add this code just right above that code:

```
query_posts('cat=3&paged='.get_query_var( 'paged' ));
```

Things to note from above `query_posts` snippet is:

- **cat**: this is the category ID you want to query. To easily see what ID is on a particular category, you can use [ShowID for Post/Page/Category/Tag/Comment](http://ounziw.com/2010/02/05/showid/) plugin.
- **paged**: Paged will allow your custom page to handle next & prev navigations, which is handled by [next_post_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link) and [prev_post_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_post_link). As for [get_query_var( 'paged' )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) is function to get what page's page you currently see.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. I'm going to explore custom post types first, but if that doesn't work I'm going to use this :) Thanks everyone else for the answers as well!

Comment: This is all covered on the Codex entry i linked to in my answer, and you don't even need to know the category ID following the codex example.